# Extending a GNU make implicit rule

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, upx

I'm using the GNU make [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for linking together my binary as follows:

```
foo : foo.o bar.o
```

However, I also want to be able to compile the resulting binary `foo` with [UPX](https://upx.github.io/) (by invoking `upx ultra-brute foo`) on it afterwards. I can, of course, do something like this:

```
foo : foo.o bar.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
    upx --ultra-brute $@
```

However, this is basically forcing me to repeat the implicit rule, while all I really want to do is just also call `upx ultra-brute` after what it already does anyway. Is there a way to get what I want without basically having to manually write the implicit rule into the recipe anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That invocation of `upx` modifies the file in-place, which means that if it fails or is interrupted, `make` won't know to run it again. In general you should avoid writing Makefile rules like that.

If we split it up then it becomes easy:

```
foo.fat: foo.o bar.o
foo: foo.fat
    upx --ultra-brute -o $@ $<
```

Comment: This will only work if there's a prerequisite called ``foo.fat.o`` available for the implicit rule to trigger on. However, I don't mind naming my tests that way, so it works for me.